# HLS with Jplayer

Tags: html, safari, jplayer

Could anyone let me know if you have any experience in playing an HLS stream in a HTML5 Browser using the jplayer. This seems to work only in Safari. I even tried using the fiddle section on jplayer.org but this too only works on Safari. Here is the code that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function(event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4v: "http://pkhdliveuss-lh.akamaihd.net/i/Live_1@xyz/master.m3u8"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/latest/js",
        supplied: "m4v"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know jplayer, but I doubt it can play HLS on anything other than browsers that have native support (safari). JWPlayer Premium can do it and video.js is working on it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with HLS Provider https://github.com/mangui/HLSprovider you can find a howto [here](http://www.razvantudorica.com/12/how-to-play-hls-with-jwplayer/)

Comment: it's jPlayer, not JWPlayer. Not the same software.